# Entendo uma execução paralela usando _thread. Existe alguma forma mais pythonica de escrever o mesmo código?

Tags: python, python-3.x, thread

```
import _thread
def filho(tid):
    print('Ola da thread', tid)

def pai():
    i = 0
    while True:
        i += 1
        _thread.start_new_thread(filho, (i,))
        if input() == 'q': break

pai()
```

Existe alguma forma mais pythonica de escrever o mesmo código?

Comment: O que o seu código deveria fazer, exatamente?

Comment: @Anderson Carlos Woss : a ideia é executar as funções pai e filho em paralelo!